# How multiple tomcats share data among themseves?

Tags: tomcat

no idea whether i am asking a valid question ! but suddenly got this doubt so trying to clear my doubt.

Consider there are 2 tomcats running and when a clients requests for a servlet and this request is handled by tomcatA and at the same time if one more request that is dependent on first request gets handled by tomcatB, i want to know how the tomcats share data between them??does the 2nd request will be paused until first request is processed completly??

Thanks in advance

Comment: By spraying on the bushes mostly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and your question is very open-ended so I wouldn't be surprised if it gets voted CLOSED. In the meantime, I can think of several ways to "share" data between Tomcat instances:

1. [memcached](http://memcached.org/)
2. [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service)
3. Good-old relational database
4. Hand-rolled notification system to communicate directly over socket, etc.

As for having one request "wait" for another to complete, that's where things start to get dangerous: you can easily design deadlocks into your system which can lock-up the whole cluster while every request waits for another request.

I can't imagine a use-case where multiple clients are waiting on each other's work to complete before their work can complete, but that the clients wouldn't be tolerant of missing prerequisite data.

Comment: Thank you Christopher.. I ll check the memcached as well as JMX thanks again for the reply.